# Prevent the user to accidentally touch the UI of app while closing the app in iphone X

Tags: iphone-x

[Image of my main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AWHY.png)

I'm building a timer app which sets the timer by scrolling it. The problem I'm facing is when the user tries to close the app on an iphone X, sometimes, they accidentally scroll the timer and them do in the background which sets a notification which the user didn't intended. I need suggestions on how to handle that.

What I'm thinking right now is to set a view at the bottom and make it transparent. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to understand how close the elements are?

Comment: yeah sure, I just did

Comment: feels more like a question for the User Experience stackexchange.